# How to read year info from MBR

Tags: c++, bootloader, mbr

I want to fetch the year information from the MBR. Here is my approach for this problem.

For any program, whenever we use 'version' flag we get the year information also. I gues it is the release year of that tool.
For example,

```
ls --version

ls (GNU coreutils) 8.25
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Richard M. Stallman and David MacKenzie.
```

Q1. Does the MBR contain the year's info?
Q2. If yes, How I can fetch it?

I can fetch the version info like this

1. read the first 512 bytes, seek the offset(0x3E) and read the next 2 chars.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: ??? (visible confusion) If you want to see what can be in an MBR: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record -- basically the only reliably mandatory bit is the two-byte boot signature at the end.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to do? It is possible that unless you have a very specific MBR variant in mind, A1 = no.

Comment: There is no date information in the MBR. There is no versioning info in the MBR at all.

Comment: `For any program` you won't be sure like that. Lots of programs don't ever care about printing year in version. Why would they? Especially when they don't care about copyrights of their source code